# Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Vue'.Vetur(2339) when trying to access parent method from child component (with class-based vue components)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, parent-child, vue-class-components

I am using [class-based vue components](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) and am trying to access a parent's (of a parent's) method within a child component for various reasons. The syntax is as follows for the definition of my class-component and the line where I try to access the parent method:

```js
export default class ListStoragePlace extends Vue {

    @Prop({ required: true })
    readonly id!: number
    checkbox: boolean = false

    @Watch("checkbox")
    onPropertyChanged() {
        this.$parent.$parent.updateSelected(this.id, this.checkbox)
    }
}
```

The code functions as intended and it calls up the parent method on a property change in the child, but the [Vetur](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/) plugin (for Vue 2 projects) still sees it as an error, thus breaking pipelines and causing other issues.

This is the specific error: [image: error example]

The parent component and its method is defined as follows:

```js
export default class Table extends Vue {
    updateSelected(id: number, status: boolean) {
        if (status) {
            this.selected.push(id)
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.selected.length; i++) {
                if (this.selected[i] === id) {
                    this.selected.splice(i, 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a solution or even simply a workaround to get rid of the error, please let me know.

Comment: You can type an instance manually in case its type is unknown. this.$parent.$parent is a terrible practice, the use of $parent should be avoided. Due to how comps are used, you can't guarantee that a grandparent is a component that you expect

Comment: @EstusFlask What do you mean exactly with 'type an instance manually in case its type is unknown', could you show me an example? Many thanks.

Comment: `value as unknown as MyCompType`

Comment: @EstusFlask like so? :
```const method: unknown = this.$parent.$parent.updateSelected(this.id, this.checkbox)
```

Comment: `(this.$parent.$parent as unknown as MyCompType).updateSelected(...)`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions . But again, what you're trying to do should never happen in properly written Vue app. $parent is a remnant of Vue 1 that borrowed it from Angular, and it has already been considered bad at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First and foremost, it is important to realize `this.$parent` is a *terrible* practice and should not be used** (it is a remnant functionality from Vue 1).

If you desperately need a temporary work-around, you can use the following syntax to remove the error (solution given by [@Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask)):

```js
(this.$parent.$parent as unknown as MyCompType).updateSelected(...)
```

*`MyCompType` is the name of your class-based component.*

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions